# List of dataframes to RDD in separate partition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cluster-computing, rdd, partitioning

I have a list of spark dataframes and I have to perform some operation on them
I want to create a rdd from this such that each dataframe goes in a separate partition so that I can simply use mapPartitions on this rdd to perform computation on each dataframe in parallel on separate nodes.

Comment: Are the schema's of each of your dataframes the same, or do they have different columns?

Comment: @RyanWidmaier.. the schema is same for all dataframes. Since the computation I want to perform involve rolling computations such as running sum etc and each dataframe is data of different object so I don't want different dataframes to be in same partition as then rolling computations will be calculated wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is some code to achieve this.  The general approach is just to union all of your data together and add a `source` column to label where each row came from.  The union call shouldn't change the partitioning of the **DataFrames**, just combine the partitions all into one uber **DataFrame**.  If you do have something that is causing reshuffling, you could add a column with the original partition id using `spark_partition_id()` and then call `repartition` on the `source` and `partition_id` columns.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, lit, col

df1 = sc.parallelize([
    (1, 2, 3),
    (2, 3, 4)
]).toDF(["col1", "col2", "col3"])

df2 = sc.parallelize([
    (3, 4, 5),
    (4, 5, 6)
]).toDF(["col1", "col2", "col3"])

# Setup the DF's for union.  Their columns need to be in the same order and
# add a source column
df1_union = df1.select(lit("df1").alias("source"), *[col(c) for c in sorted(df1.columns)])
df2_union = df2.select(lit("df2").alias("source"), *[col(c) for c in sorted(df2.columns)])

# You could do this instead if the schemas are different
# df1_union = df1.select(lit("df1").alias("source"), struct(*df1.columns).alias("df1"), lit(None).alias("df2"))
# df2_union = df2.select(lit("df2").alias("source"), lit(None).alias("df1"), struct(*df2.columns).alias("df2"))

combined = df1_union.unionAll(df2_union) 

combined.show()
combined.rdd.mapPartitions(lambda row: do whatever..)
```

Note, here is what the data of combined looks like:

```
+------+----+----+----+
|source|col1|col2|col3|
+------+----+----+----+
|   df1|   1|   2|   3|
|   df1|   2|   3|   4|
|   df2|   3|   4|   5|
|   df2|   4|   5|   6|
+------+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this will the partitioning occur based on source column? I mean will all the data of same source go to the same partition? I want to perform running sums on data from each source and so cannot have different source data in same partition..thanks a lot for the help...much appreciated...

Comment: No shuffles will occur in the above example.  Union just puts all the original partitions from the listed DataFrames into one DF without moving any rows.  You can run combined.explain() to see that.  In other words, if you have DF1 w/ partitions A & B, and DF2 with partitions C & D, combined will have partitions A, B, C & D

Comment: The individual dataframes do not have any partitions . I am simply reading them from parquet file. Does it mean then that each individual dataframe will go to separate partition with UnionAll ? Sorry I am new to spark. Thanks a lot ..

Comment: It's a little confusing in that partition sometimes means an input split (some number of records) and sometimes it's a slice of the data by a value (ie, partition by month).  In this context I am talking about the former.  The parquet reader will load in your data, dividing records up into Input Splits so they can be processed in parallel.  If you do df.rdd.getNumPartitions() you can see how many partitions it created.  Alternatively you can look at the Spark UI for the number of tasks.

Comment: I checked the partitions on my input dataframes and its 1. UnionAll works and final rdd has two partitions (one for each dataframe). However, there are some input dataframes that have 2 partitions. I would like to move them to 1 as well so that final rdd has as many partitions as the number of dataframes ? Also, from the rdd generated after action on mapPartitions, how do i split the output corresponding to each input dataframe to separate output dataframes ?

Comment: There is no easy way to divide an RDD or DF into multiples, and typically you don't want to.  Reading between the lines it sounds like you are trying to solve the problem using mapPartitions when you would be better off looking at DataFrame.groupBy(..) or the windowing functions.  Those work like SQL group by operations basically to allow you to compute aggregate functions over rows.